Why are there only two chiralities?
We have a right hand and a left hand. Many molecules likewise have left and right versions. Is this a feature of 3-d space and perhaps in higher dimensional spaces, there would be more than one chirality? This doesn't seem like its the case since even in higher dimensions, we have reflection matrices. And those reflection matrices also go back and forth between two states.
I have some intuition that this is related to there being two signs, positive and negative. But nothing concrete.
Can chirality be motivated from something like positive and negative signs in a way that one can be convinced there will always be two chiralities for objects in any dimensional space?

Are you aware of the linear algebra definition of the positive/negative orientation of a basis of $\mathbb R^n$? And further developments of the concept of orientation of $n$-dimensional manifolds?

I guess if the determinant of the matrix formed by the basis vectors is +1, its a positive orientation and otherwise its negative? Not familiar with his this extends to manifolds. Any references?

Intuitively, if two rigid bodies exist in a space, can we move one of them using translations and rotations so that it coincides with the other? We either can or we can't. The distance preserving transformations are translations, rotations and reflections, but we cannot perform reflections in physical space.

What you might be looking for is the concept of orientation. That concept arises first in linear algebra, where (as you say in the comment) an ordered basis $v_1,...,v_n$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is positively oriented if and only if the matrix with columns $v_1,....,v_n$ has positive determinant, otherwise it is negatively oriented. This works in any dimension.  As you suggest, a reflection matrix --- which is one kind of change-of-basis matrix that has negative determinant --- switches the two orientations: under a reflection a positively oriented basis is transformed into a negatively oriented basis; and a negatively oriented basis is transformed into a positively oriented basis.
More generally, in any finite dimensional vector space $V$, there is an equivalence relation on bases of $V$ with precisely two equivalence classes, called the two orientations of $V$: two bases determine the same orientation if and only if the change of basis matrix has positive determinant; otherwise they have opposite orientations. This also works in any dimension. Again, reflection transformations of $V$ will swap the two orientations.
From there, the concept of orientation makes its way into the study of smooth manifolds: for any $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, at each point $p \in M$ its tangent space is an $n$-dimensional vector space $T_p M$; and an orientation of $M$ is a continuous function of $p$ that assigns an orientation to each vector space $T_p M$. I don't know if you have the background for this, but if you are interested you can pick up a good book on differential topology and learn about orientations of smooth manifolds (among other things).

We can also view this through matroids. A matroid $M$ is a pair $(E,\mathcal{I})$, where $E$ is a finite "ground set" and $\mathcal{I}$ is a collection of subsets of $E$, called independent sets, satisfying axioms analogous to those of linearly independent sets in a vector space. An oriented matroid is a matroid equipped with sign data that tells us how each circuit (or base) is "oriented."
Suppose $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a finite set of vectors. For any linear dependence
$$\alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n = 0$$
with coefficients $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$, we record the pattern of signs: which $\alpha_i$ are positive, which are negative, and which are zero. This sign pattern must obey certain consistency rules in order to arise from an actual vector configuration, and these rules are precisely the axioms of an oriented matroid. In that sense, an oriented matroid captures the orientation data of a real vector configuration without needing to store the full real coordinates, only their sign behavior.
If we interpret each vector $v_i$ as lying on one side or another of various hyperplanes, the sign of $\alpha_i$ indicates which side of a hyperplane $v_i$ is on (positive vs. negative), and a zero coefficient indicates that $v_i$ lies on the hyperplane itself. Two such sign patterns are said to have the same global orientation if one can be obtained from the other by simultaneously flipping all of the signs. This is similar to the "two-way toggle" seen in real vector spaces, where two ordered bases differ by a single reflection precisely when their determinants differ by a sign.
